# How to shutdown ClassPathXmlApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring

I have this code...

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
 ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
}
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
    xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws
        http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd
        http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs
        http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd">    
</beans>
```

The code exits, but the JVM never stops.

Anyone any ideas why its doesn't stop?

I've also tried a new Main method of the following, but it keeps running.

public static void main(String[] args)
    {
     ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
    ((ConfigurableApplicationContext)context).registerShutdownHook();
    ((ConfigurableApplicationContext)context).stop();
    System.out.println("exiting NOW...");
    }

If I pause the JVM, it shows 4 threads.

1 with TimerThread.run()

3 with ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.take()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ConfigurableApplicationContext` interface (that `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` implements) has a `close` method you need to call in order for the JVM to shut down properly.

More information can be found [here.](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ConfigurableApplicationContext.html#close--)